# How to access azure devops apis via an azure app?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get the jwt access token to call some azure devops API endpoints.

I first Get the code via oauth endpoint:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&prompt=select_account&scope=CLIENT_ID/.default&redirect_uri=https://foo.bar.com/auth

CLIENT_ID/.default ==
user_impersonation and
User.Read

this returns me a `code`

I then use this code to make a post request to:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

with

```
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:CLIENT_ID
client_secret:SECRET
scope:CLIENT_ID/.default
redirect_uri:https://foo.bar.com/auth
code:CODE
```

this returns me an `access_token`. However this access token doesn't seem to be able to do much.

I have tried it with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/me/` (It always returns `Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.`) and `https://dev.azure.com/paradime-io/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=2.0` (just html for me to login) - both using `Authorization: Bearer {access_token}` header but they do not work.

I have also tried to use it with `git clone...` username & password but that is also not working.

I have also tried to use `on_behalf_of` and the `/token` endpoint:

```
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id:CLIENT_ID
client_secret:SECRET
scope:CLIENT_ID/.default
//client_assertion_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-beare
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
assertion:CODE
```

but the returned `access_token` is also not useable on the other API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access **Azure DevOps APIs** via Azure AD application, you need to generate jwt access token with **`499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default`** scope.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

To get  **authorization code**, I ran below authorization request in browser before acquiring token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran above request in browser, I got  **`code`**  value successfully in address bar like this:

[image]

I generated  **access token**  using authorization code flow successfully via Postman by including above code in below request:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
code: <paste_code_from_above_request>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**
[image]

When I used above **access token** to call following DevOps API, I got response successfully like below:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/<orgname>/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=2.0
```

**Response:**

[image]

To call Microsoft Graph, you need to change the **scope** value to **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** while acquiring access token.