# Is it possible to acquire an access token for app service with a system-assigned managed identity?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-repos

I want to access Azure Repos from my app service with a system-assigned managed identity.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68376718/using-oauth2-token-of-azure-devops-services-application-to-clone-a-git-repositor), it is possible to access Azure Repos git with an access token but I can't find how to acquire an access token from my app service with a system-assigned managed identity.

I think it also needs to grant permission to Azure DevOps resources to my app service for acquiring an access token.

I tried that

- Added my system-assigned managed identity to organization users and Project Administrators group.
- get token from TokenCredential and access git with the token

```java
var token = tokenCredential.getTokenSync(
            new TokenRequestContext().addScopes("https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/.default"));
```

and access to git with this url.

```
https://[the access token]@dev.azure.com/orgname/projname/_git/reponame
```

It resulted an unauthorized error.

Comment: Could you try changing scope to `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default`? Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76377820/how-to-access-azure-devops-apis-via-an-azure-app/76405616#76405616

Comment: @Sridevi Thank you for your comment. I tried, but ended with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with Azure VM which has `system-managed identity`, it can work on my side.

Steps below:

1. Please add `contributor` role of the subscription for the `system-managed identity`, otherwise it will report error for azure login command.
   [image]
2. Please add the identity to the DevOps organization and target project.
   [image]

The doc has shared [sample command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#q-can-i-use-a-service-principal-or-managed-identity-with-azure-cli) to get access token for service principal and managed-identity.

1. [install azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=powershell#powershell), restart a new PS window, use command `az login --identity` to login.
2. After login, you can get the accesstoken:

```
$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 --query "accessToken" --output tsv
```

You can  put the token in the url to repo or use for rest api :

[image]

Since you are using app service, and `system-managed identity` only works on the azure resource, you could need to login with identity in app service and request the access token in the app service.

Comment: Hmm, I could add my app service to the organization.

Comment: Thanks @h-okhs! I have updated the reply. I don't have app service but tried vm with sysmte-managed idenitity.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. It seems a right way, but not succeeded with my app service. :(